# Problem with .eq() when comparing dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to compare two dataframes (df and df2) using .eq(), but it gives me false. I'm sure about the values:

> print(df['ano'])
> 0    2021
> Name: ano, dtype: int64

> print(df2['ano'])
> 0     2020
> 1     2019
> 2     2019
> 3     2018
> 4     2017
> ... 
> 89    2020
> 90    2017
> 91    2018
> 92    2021
> 93    2021
> Name: ano, Length: 94, dtype: int64

> print(df['ano'].eq(df2['ano']))
> 0     False
> 1     False
> 2     False
> 3     False
> 4     False
> ...  
> 89    False
> 90    False
> 91    False
> 92    False
> 93    False
> Name: ano, Length: 94, dtype: bool

Comment: what do you expect to get?

Comment: I expect a true, cause 2021 = 2021, doesn't?

Comment: it doesn't work as you think, read [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html#pandas.Series.eq)

Comment: I'm trying to find df (single row dataframe) inside the df2 (big dataframe). I have 3 columns, it gives me true on 2 and always false on the 'ano' column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates()

x = 0

y = 0

df = df.reset_index()

df2 = df2.reset_index()

while(x = len(df)):

    while(y = len(df2)):

        if((df.at[x, 'a'] == df2.at[y, 'a']) & (df.at[x, 'b'] == df2.at[y, 'b']) & (df.at[x, 'c'] == df2.at[y, 'c'])):

           print('found')
        y += 1
    x += 1
    y = 0
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`Series.eq(other)` compares two Series element wise, if you want to compare `df2['ano']` with the first element in `df1['ano']`, you can use `Series.item()` or `Series.iloc[0]`

```py
print(df2['ano'].eq(df['ano'].item()))
# or
print(df2['ano'].eq(df['ano'].iloc[0]))
```

If you want to check if element in `df['ano']` is in `df2['ano']`, you can use `Series.isin`

```
print(df['ano'].isin(df2['ano']))
```

Comment: I'm trying print(df[columns].isin(df2[columns])) and columns has ['ano', 'b', 'c'] for example, but I can`t get all true, I guess because the indexers

Comment: @null92 Common usecase for `isin` is `isin(1D array)`, if you want to check multiple columns. I recommend loop through the columns.

Comment: How? Using for?

Comment: @null92 Yes, loop the columns and replace `ano` with the variable.

Comment: Can't be this way, I have to verify all the 3 columns at the same time, cause I have: df (1 row x 3 columns) and df2 (94 rows x 3 columns). I have to catch 3 trues, otherwords, find df inside df2